# rails password update validation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, passwords

I have the following validation:

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true, :length => { :within => 6..40 }, :format => { :with => pass_regex }, :unless => :nopass?
```

Then, when I try to update without password (nopass? is true) the following errors appear:

```
There were problems with the following fields:

Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
Password is invalid
```

Notice that the :unless works on :presence and :confirmation but not in :lenght or :format.

How could I fix this?

Comment: which Rails version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some strange issues with the :confirmation flag as well, which I never figured out, but that's how I solved the problem in my Rails 3.0.x app:

```
attr_accessor :password_confirmation

validates :password, :presence => true, :length => {:within => PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH..PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH}

validate :password_is_confirmed

  def password_is_confirmed
 if password_changed? # don't trigger that validation every time we save/update attributes
  errors.add(:password_confirmation, "can't be blank") if password_confirmation.blank?
  errors.add(:password_confirmation, "doesn't match first password") if password != password_confirmation
 end
end
```

I realise this is not an explanation why your code isn't working, but if you're looking for a quick temporary fix - I hope this will help.

Comment: How do you define password_changed? I encrypt the password before saving.

Comment: For all attributes you automatically get a _changed? method, that's coming from ActiveRecord. You can actually try using it like that:
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :password_changed?
Haven't tried that myself, but you might be able to fit it in your code above. (note: you still need the attr_accessor :password_confirmation in this case; I think :confirmation => true is supposed to do exactly that)

Answer (score 0):

You might use [conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :surname, :presence => true, :if => "name.nil?"
end
```